# Chain shell commands in Node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process

I need to `kextunload driver.kext && kextload driver.kext`.

I always use `child_proces` spawn function but don't know how to chain with it.

Here's an example of how I use it

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
spawn('afplay', ['fanfare.mp3', '-t', '6']);
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html There are synchronous methods at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the streaming capabilities of `spawn()`, you could just easily use `exec()` instead, like:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('kextunload driver.kext && kextload driver.kext', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: And if he do need streaming? :-P

Comment: @JanJůna Then use `spawn()`? For programs/commands like 'kextload'/'kextunload', there really isn't any need to stream the output.

Comment: For other commands, it can be important to stream output instead of buffering it into memory (which can result in `Max buffer size error`). I found out that Node v6 has new option parameter `shell: true/false` which will run whole command so you can just call `let spawnProcess = spawn("ls && ls && ls", {shell: true})` and it will work.

Comment: @JanJůna Right, you could use that config option for node v6+.